# Regular Expression for filetype

Tags: java, regex, jsf, file-upload

I use it in my File-Upload by using them to validate all file type excepts image file such as (.jpg or .png).
How can I use them?

This is my code

```
allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(png)$/"
```

Comment: why not `split` based on `.` and check for `.equals("png")|"jpg")`?. Wouldn't this be simpler?

Comment: More context (Primefaces?)

Comment: Whats the context of your usage? On the jsf page or in the controllers? Have a look at this: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml

Comment: Simply use `String#endsWith(".png")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check any type of file type extension.Try this one

```
^.*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|doc|DOC|pdf|PDF)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `matches()` with a case-insensitive regex:

```
if (filename.matches("(?i).*\\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)$"))
    // it's an image file
```

The term `(?i)` is a flag that turns on case insensitivity.

Add other extensions as you wish.

The regex should be portable, so if the context is not in fact java (as I suspect) you may have to specify the regex using options for the case insensitivity:

```
/.*\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)$/i
```